Visual studio extension for team explorer
I am working with Azure DevOps and using the Team Explorer in Visual Studio to manage work items. When creating or editing a work item, I need to automatically copy the value from a source field to a target field either when the source field loses focus or when its value changes.
How can I achieve this with Visual Studio Extensions?
I initially attempted to achieve this using a Work Item Type Definition (WITD) with the whenchange element. However, this approach only copies the previously saved value of the field when the source changes, not the current (i.e., newly input) value.

Hi @Subrahmanya, have you tried onFieldChanged event? Feel free to let me know if you have any question.

Hi @Ziyang Liu-MSFT yes i tried with onFieldChanged event It is working now. Thank you.

You can try to use onFieldChanged event. According to official doc,

Fired after a field has changed. If the field change ran rules which updated other fields, all these changes are part of a single event.

This event is triggered when the value of a field changes, and you can use it to copy the new value from the source field to the target field. See the example here.
